# Getting value of attribute and testing it with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have an XML dump and am trying to parse it with `Nokogiri` to get a text value of an attribute, then find out if it matches a certain string I'm looking for.  Here is a snippet of my XML file:

```
      #(Element:0x3fc58cc091f8 {
      name = "host",
      attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fc58cc08528 { name = "starttime", value = "1481896934" }), #(Attr:0x3fc58cc08514 { name = "endtime", value = "1481896947" })],
      children = [
        #(Element:0x3fc58af6bdc0 {
          name = "status",
          attributes = [
            #(Attr:0x3fc58af6b6f4 { name = "state", value = "up" }),
            #(Attr:0x3fc58af6b6e0 { name = "reason", value = "arp-response" }),
            #(Attr:0x3fc58af6b6cc { name = "reason_ttl", value = "0" })]
          }),
        #(Text "\n"),
        #(Element:0x3fc58a744fe8 {
          name = "os",
          children = [
            #(Element:0x3fc58c1392f0 {
              name = "osmatch",
              attributes = [
                #(Attr:0x3fc58c1381d4 { name = "name", value = "Microsoft Windows XP SP2 or SP3, or Windows Server 2003" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fc58c1381c0 { name = "accuracy", value = "100" }),
                #(Attr:0x3fc58c1381ac { name = "line", value = "57766" })],
              children = [
                #(Text "\n"),
                #(Element:0x3fc58ae89e70 {
                  name = "osclass",
                  attributes = [
                    #(Attr:0x3fc58ae893bc { name = "type", value = "general purpose" }),
                    #(Attr:0x3fc58ae893a8 { name = "vendor", value = "Microsoft" }),
                    #(Attr:0x3fc58ae89394 { name = "osfamily", value = "Windows" }),
                    #(Attr:0x3fc58ae89380 { name = "osgen", value = "XP" }),
                    #(Attr:0x3fc58ae8936c { name = "accuracy", value = "100" })],
                  children = [ #(Element:0x3fc58b19428c { name = "cpe", children = [ #(Text "cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_xp")] })]
                  }),
                #(Text "\n"),
```

So, what I'm trying to do is get the contents of `os/osmatch/@name.value`.  In this case it would be `Windows XP SP2 or SP3, or Windows Server 2003`.

I've got that part down:

```
 doc.xpath("//host").each do |host|
   os = host.at_xpath("os/osmatch").at_xpath("@name").value rescue nil
 end

 output: Microsoft Windows XP SP2 or SP3, or Windows Server 2003
```

Typically, my XML file will have tons of hosts with different OSes though, so the output will likely look something like:

```
 Microsoft Windows XP SP2 or SP3, or Windows Server 2003
 Ubuntu 14.04 Linux
 Microsoft Windows 7, or Microsoft Windows 8
 FreeBSD X.X.X
 ....
```

What I'm trying to do is match certain strings to the values I'm looking for now, so I can do some action if `Windows XP` is found for instance.

```
 doc.xpath("//host").each do |host|
   os = host.at_xpath("os/osmatch").at_xpath("@name[contains(value, 'Windows XP')]")
 end
```

But instead, I'm getting an error, so I know I'm doing something wrong.  I've tried some other variations, but can't figure out how to do it:

```
 Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid expression: @name[contains(value, 'Windows']
```

Comment: You should probably give an example of the actual XML, rather than the output of the parsed result, that way people can reproduce your issue and test solutions.

Comment: @matt Sorry... it was really long.  trying to save the eyes!

Comment: "it was really long. trying to save the eyes! " Please read "[mcve]". We appreciate the sentiment, but you do need to strip the input XML down to the minimal amount that demonstrates the problem prior to posting. That process of stripping your code and the input often reveals the problem to you without the need to ask the question. And, as @matt said, the XML is useful to us. The inspected DOM isn't nearly as useful as we can't reuse it to test solutions. What it comes down to is we need you to help us help you.

Comment: Be very wary of using a trailing `rescue nil`. It will rescue Exception on down, which can mask syntax errors in code resulting in very hard to locate bugs.

Comment: @theTinMan The `rescue` modifier only rescues `StandardError` down, so strictly speaking won’t mask `SyntaxError`. (I’m being a bit pedantic here–your point still stands as it will mask `NameError`s which can be caused by typos, as well as other errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
host.at_xpath("os/osmatch[contains(@name,'Windows')]")
```

Comment: Ok, so that returns the whole element.  I'm just needing to get the `@name` value to return.

Comment: Query it further as you did. It is xpath element.

Comment: Ah, gotcha!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up Xpath and Ruby code. Your working code is

```
at_xpath("@name").value
```

Here `@name` is the XPath query, and this returns a `Node` object to Ruby. This object has a `value` method that returns the value of the attribute as a string, but `value` is *not* valid XPath.

You try to change this by adding a predicate:

```
at_xpath("@name[contains(value, 'Windows XP')]")
```

Here you’re trying to use the Ruby `value` method in the XPath. This doesn’t work. However, in XPath you can use `.` (i.e. a dot) to select the current node, and this is what you want here:

```
at_xpath("@name[contains(., 'Windows XP')]")
```

This will give you the `name` attribute of the current node (the thing you’re calling `at_xpath` on) if it contains the string “Windows XP”.